# PyTorch tensor indexing or conditional selection?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
    for c in range(self.n_class):
        target[c][label == c] = 1
```

self.n_class is 32. and target is 32 x 1024 x 2048 tensor.

I know that target[c] select the each one of 1 x 1024 x 2048. 
But I don't understand [label == c].

Because by thumb of rule, an integer should go in the square [].

Could someone explain what second square does and how it makes sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PyTorch supports "Advanced Indexing." It implements the ability to accept a tensor argument to the `[]` operator.

The result of the `==` operator is a boolean mask. The `[]` operator is using that mask to select elements. This example below might help clarify:

```
>>> x=torch.arange(0,10)
>>> x
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> x < 5
tensor([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
>>> x[x < 5]
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> x[x > 5]
tensor([6, 7, 8, 9])
>>>
```

Some general docs:
https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/BasicIndexing.html

Advanced indexing in numpy:
https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html